# Convert lambda expressions to SQL in an ORM?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, reflection, orm

How could I write an ORM that would convert LINQ into SQL?

I already have made an existing ORM, but I want to improve it with LINQ, so that I, for instance would be able to say:

```
MyORMObject.GetAll(o => o.firstName == "peter");
```

The idea in my head is that the system would then take that and convert it into a query. I guess the hard part is to read the stuff parsed into the LINQ part.

How do I do this? In other words, how would I (through Reflection or something else) read the `FirstName` property being used, and its desired match, "Peter"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to need to [implement an IQueryable LINQ Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb546158(v=vs.110).aspx).  You won't be using reflection by the way, you'll be using [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.aspx) trees.

Answer (score 3):

If your method is `IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>>)`, then the lambda expression will be compiled as an expression tree, with an `Equals` sub-expression, which in turn has a `MemberExpression` containing the `FirstName` property, and a `ConstantExpression` containing the string.